# Updating an image using jquery and programmatically

Tags: jquery, image, src

I have an unordered list that I populate with some li items programatically:

```
 function addNewElement(elem) {

     var li = $("<li></li>");

     li.prop("class", "ui-state-default");
     li.prop("id", elem.Alias);
     li.text(elem.Name);

     var newItem = '<div id="' + elem.Alias + '-Status" class="elementStatus"><div class="image"><img id="' + elem.Alias + '-StatusImg" src="@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif")"></div><div id="' + elem.Alias + '-StatusTxt" class="text">Waiting...</div></div>';
     console.log("new item added: " + newItem);
     li.append(newItem);
     li.appendTo($(getSortableContainer(elem.Alias)));
 };
```

the function getSortableContainer is an unordered list (ul item).

During a long task is executed, it is visible an image and under the image the text "Waiting". After I get the result of the long task, I update the image of the above img within the div (the src property) using the following:

```
function setImg(elemId) {
    $('#' + elemId + '-StatusImg').attr("src", '@Url.Content("~/images/MyImage.gif")');
    $('#' + elemId + '-StatusTxt').text("Done!");
}
```

The problem is that when I update the image with a new one using the above function, the image is not updated immediatelly, it is updated after a few seconds, more than 15 seconds.

How can I force the image to be updated immediately?

**UPDATED 2013.10.24**:

I am using below lines to update the image to prevent caching:

```
var d = new Date();
$('#' + elemId + '-StatusImg').prop("src", '@Url.Content("~/images/MyImage.gif")' + '#' + d.getTime());
```

Using it, first time my web app is launched (by previously removing all Internet Explorer history, cookies, etc.), images continue being displayed with a delay. Next times, if I launch again my web app, without deleting internet explorer history, images are then displayed immediatelly so... what's happening?

Comment: where your call to setImg?

Comment: Is that a big image? Have you tried loading a smaller image?

Comment: use for example data-src="" for your url, write it in and then change the sre to data-src, it will work yo

Comment: @Dvir when the long task finishes. The long task is a deferred ajax task.

Comment: @undefined not, the image is 1,39KB only.

Comment: and the text have a delay also?

Comment: @Dvir no, the text is displayed immediately.

Comment: @johnSmith you mean, changing all src to data-src?

Comment: Can you upload it to out server?